# Configure company completion to allow typing non-matching characters

Tags: company-mode

I am a newbie to emacs and know nothing about lisp.
I just want to config some features for autocompletion.

Here is how I config company-mode now:

```
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list
    'company-backends '(company-irony-c-headers company-irony)))
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-irony))
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(global-set-key "\t" 'company-complete-common)
```

I want the auto complete pop up window to be closed when I type any character. For example, I type "ab" and I hit , the auto complete window pop up. I was unable to type any character that is not in the auto complete list. So, I want when I type "c", the pop-up window close and "c" should be inputted.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs SX!  Please try to ask only one question per topic, and please use descriptive titles for your questions.  Thank you

Comment: I've changed the title to more clearly reflect what I believe you are asking here. Feel free to change it again if I've missed the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
(setq company-require-match nil)
```

This tells company not to require what you type to match a completion candidate. If you start completion you should then be able to type something that doesn't match to cancel the completion and keep typing normally.

Note that you can use a `progn` to perform multiple steps within a single `eval-after-load`. For example:

```
(eval-after-load 'company
    '(progn
        (add-to-list 'company-backends ....)
        (add-to-list 'company-backends ....)
        (setq company-require-match nil)))
```